# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch while using Spring Custom Argument Resolver

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, illegalargumentexception

I am getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch while using Spring Argument resolver with **HandlerMethodArgumentResolver**. debugged my code many times but able to find why this exception is coming. it will be great if anyone can help me with this.
this is my code.

```
public final class SpringArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return CommonHeader.class.isAssignableFrom(parameter.getParameterType());
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

        CommonHeader commonHeader = new CommonHeader();

        String user_id = webRequest.getHeader("UserID");
       
        commonHeader.setUser_id(user_id);

            return commonHeader;
    }
```

Config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringWebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        resolvers.add(new SpringArgumentResolver());
    }

}
```

CommonHeader class:

```
public class CommonHeader {

    private String user_id;
    private String ip_address;
    private String request_id;

    public CommonHeader(String user_id) {
            this.user_id = user_id;
    }
    public CommonHeader(){}
 
    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("user_data")
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<JsonNode>> getUserPreferenceData(GetDataRequest getDataRequest) {
            DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<JsonNode>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
         // some logic 
        //  some logic
       return deferredResult;
    }
```

Request class which extends CommonHeader class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class GetDataRequest extends CommonHeader {

    private String name1;
    private String name2;
   
}
```

Comment: And the problem is? YOur `GetNotificationPrefrenceDataRequest` is nowhere used in that code, so why should it use a converter?

Comment: it was typing mistake only, as this example code. some fields of the header are common for all the APIs of my project. so that's I'm applying this argument resolver code for code optimization purposes.

Comment: exception coming at the point after return statement in SpringArgumentResolver class, return commonHeader;

Comment: So and how do you think a `CommonHeader` automagically  becomes a `GetDataRequest`? Doing `GetDataRequest req = (GetDataRequest) new CommonHeader();` (ie. casting the `COmmonHeader` to a `GetDataRequest`) would also in regular java lead to a `ClassCastException`. So why should this be different. You need to determine the type from the `MethodParameter` and dynamically construct an instance.

Comment: but same logic for spring webflux project is working with few chnages. https://github.com/martinnemec3/spring-argument-resolver-demo/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java

Comment: Because there the object is created based on the dynamic parameter and thus will match the expected class, yours doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SpringArgumentResolver` is wrong. A `GetDataRequest` is a `CommonHeader` but a `CommonHeader` isn't a `GetDataRequest`. Your `SpringArgumentResolver` **always** returns a `CommonDataHeader` which cannot be cast/turned into a `GetDataRequest` hence the error.

```java
CommonHeader header = new CommonHeader();
GetDataRequest request = (GetDataRequest) header;
```

Is basically what you expected that automatically would happen. Now this wouldn't work in regular java (leading to a `ClassCastException`) why should it in Spring? Spring does a check to see if the resulting object can be assigned to that method argument, in this case in cannot because `GetDataRequest.isAssignableFrom(CommonHeader.class);` will return `false` (although the opposite is true!).

What you should do in your `SpringArgumentResolver` is dynamically determine the class and instantie it, cast it to `CommonHeader` and set the fields.

```java
@Override
public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

    CommonHeader commonHeader = BeanUtils.instantiateClass(parameter.getParameterType(), CommonHeader.class);
    String user_id = webRequest.getHeader("UserID");
    commonHeader.setUser_id(user_id);
    return commonHeader;
}
```

This will use the actual type of the method argument to create an instance thus eliminating the `ClassCastException` and for Spring the `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: this code is working after doing  CommonHeader commonHeader = (CommonHeader) BeanUtils.instantiateClass(parameter.getParameterType()); is this right way ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it. You need the type, you could also use `BeanUtils.instantiateClass(parameter.getParameterType(), CommonHeader.class);` that way you don't need the cast.

Comment: ok. but without casting, its giving:  "no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that capture of ? conforms to CommonHeader"

Comment: That is due to the use of generics. So either the cast or the other method is needed. I'll update the answer.